# Symfony Forms: Collection - Just Add New Entries / Prevent Modifying Old Entries

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, entity

I got a problem in my project and dont really know how to fix it. Maybe my approach is completely wrong and I should go another direction.

---

I have two Entities: Article & ArticleComment

In my ArticleType I add the Comments with a CollectionType (main reason for this is that I also want to modify the Article - basically change Article stuff and also be able to add 1 comment):

```
//ArticleType.php
$builder->add('articleComments', CollectionType::class, ['label' => false, 'entry_type' => AritcleCommentType::class, 'entry_options' => ['label' => false]]);
```

My ArticleCommentType is just a textarea field:

```
//ArticleCommentType.php
$builder->add('text', TextareaType::class, ['label' => 'comment', 'required' => false, 'attr' => ['class' => 'textarea-sm']]);
```

This solution works perfectly for me.

However, whenever I add a comment, my other comments are also rendered in a textarea field and can be edited, which I do not want. I simple want the user to add 1 comment, reload the page and maybe add another comment thats it.

I already tried to prevent rendering the other comments, but this throws an error, since the element is not in the DOM anymore - but still expected.

Any ideas how to fix this? (Hiding the fields is no valid solution for me)

---

**Update:**

My controller:

```
//ArticleController.php

...

/**
 * @Route("/article/{id}", name="app_article", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 */
public function article(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    $articleComment = new ArticleComment();
    $article->addArticleComment($articleComment);

    $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($articleComment); //cascade not active
            $em->persist($article);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'entry_saved');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_article', ['id' => $article->getId()]);
        }
        return $this->render('article/view.html.twig', ['article' => $article, 'form' => $form->createView()]);
}

...
```

Changed ArticleType:

```
$builder->add('articleComments', ArticleCommentType::class, ['label' => false, 'data' => new ArticleComment()]); //changed as suggested
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use

```
$builder
  ->add('articleComments', CollectionType::class, [
    'label' => false, 
    'entry_type' => AritcleCommentType::class, 
    'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
    'mapped' => false,
  ]);
```

you'll render the whole collection.

To me the best fitting solution is to add directly `ArticleCommentType` with `data` attribute sette to `new ArticleComment`.

If you want to display all the comments, you should do directly in the template passing all existing `ArticleComment` displaying what you need to display.

Only thing you should take care is to manually add (maybe in a form subscriber) the brand new element (if has any value) to existing collection.

Comment: thank you for you response, I updated my question with your changes but I get following error:

Could not determine access type for property "articleComments" in class "App\Entity\Article": The property "articleComments" in class "App\Entity\Article" can be defined with the methods "addArticleComment()", "removeArticleComment()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "App\Entity\ArticleComment" given.

Do you know why?

Comment: @Syllz yes, you should define the field as `mapped => false` in order to prevent symfony form component to set directly the information inside the underlying entity (you should take care of it manually)

Comment: but with mapped false the $articleComment in my Controller is another object, right? So I need to retrieve the ArticleComment object from my $form and manually save it? Thank you for your help

Comment: @Syllz you can do directly into the form, as stated before: use form subscriber directly into the type. You can use something like `POST_SUBMIT` because it happens after the form is already validated (internally).